# How can I find circular relations in a graph with Python and Networkx?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory, networkx

Consider I have the following graph:

```
A -> B
B -> C
C -> D
C -> A
```

What is the easiest way to find that A -> B -> C -> A is a circular relation?  Is there such a function already built into NetworkX or another easy to use Python library?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`networkx.simple_cycles`](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.simple_cycles.html#networkx.algorithms.cycles.simple_cycles) does this for you.

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> G = nx.DiGraph()
>>> G.add_edge('A', 'B')
>>> G.add_edge('B', 'C')
>>> G.add_edge('C', 'D')
>>> G.add_edge('C', 'A')
>>> nx.simple_cycles(G)
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'A']]
```

Comment: Link is broken. Here's a new one: https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.simple_cycles.html?highlight=simple_cycles#networkx.algorithms.cycles.simple_cycles

Answer (score 5):

Use [Depth-First Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) to detect cycles in a graph.